# Pulling variable-length strings from file name using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

**See bottom for replacement code used from answers.**

I am working with a spreadsheet that pulls names from a list of files in a directory. The files are named like `John Doe 01011980.xlsx` and `Janey B Deer 02031983.xlsx`, therefore the first and last name are of variable length, can but does not always include a middle initial and is followed by a simplified date of birth. Here is the code I am currently using (which does not work) to sort the name out of the file name.

```
Private Sub nextname_Click()

Dim strDir As String, first As String, last As String, dateofbirth As String, check As String

strDir = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text
strDir = Dir
If strDir = "" Then
    Unload Me
    MsgBox ("I couldn't find any other client files by that name.")
    Exit Sub
End If

check = Left(strDir, InStr(1, strDir, ".xlsx", vbTextCompare) - 10)

''THE ISSUE IS CONTAINED HEREIN
If InStr(1, check, " * ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    first = Trim(Left(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare) - 2))
    last = Trim(Right(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare) - 2))
Else
    first = Trim(Left(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare)))
    last = Trim(Right(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare)))
End If
''END ISSUE

dateofbirth = mid(strDir, Len(strDir) - 12, 2) & "/" & mid(strDir, Len(strDir) - 10, 2) & "/" & mid(strDir, Len(strDir) - 8, 4)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "C:\filepath\" & strDir

reviewNameUserform.first_Text.Text = first
reviewNameUserform.last_Text.Text = last
reviewNameUserform.dob_Text.Text = dateofbirth
```

The issue as marked above is in pulling the first and last name out of the file name, most especially when there is a middle initial. Currently it is only using the `Else` statement to display `John` and `Doe` or `Janey B` and `B Deer`, when I want it to detect if there is a middle initial and then pull out `John` and `Doe` or `Janey` and `Deer`. I fiddled around a lot with `Left`, `Right`, `Mid`, and `InStr` to no avail.

---

Replaced

```
check = Left(strDir, InStr(1, strDir, ".xlsx", vbTextCompare) - 10)

''THE ISSUE IS CONTAINED HEREIN
If InStr(1, check, " * ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    first = Trim(Left(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare) - 2))
    last = Trim(Right(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare) - 2))
Else
    first = Trim(Left(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare)))
    last = Trim(Right(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare)))
End If
''END ISSUE

dateofbirth = mid(strDir, Len(strDir) - 12, 2) & "/" & mid(strDir, Len(strDir) - 10, 2) & "/" & mid(strDir, Len(strDir) - 8, 4)
```

with

```
If InStr(filename, ".xlsx") = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("There is no file with that extension.")
    'Possibly include code to check for .xlsm or other extensions.
    Exit Sub
ElseIf (Len(filename) - Len(Replace(filename, " ", ""))) < 2 Then
    MsgBox ("File name format does not match expected format. File name format is FIRST M LAST mmddyyyy.xlsx")
    'Possibly include code to check for misnamed files.
    Exit Sub
Else
    filename = strDir
    filename = mid(filename, 1, InStr(filename, ".xlsx") - 1)
    dateofbirth = mid(filename, InStrRev(filename, " ") + 1)
    filename = mid(filename, 1, InStrRev(filename, " ") - 1)

    first = mid(filename, 1, InStr(filename, " ") - 1)
    filename = mid(filename, InStr(filename, " ") + 1)

    last = mid(filename, InStrRev(filename, " ") + 1)
    middlename = Trim(mid(filename, 1, InStr(filename, " ")))
End If

dateofbirth = mid(dateofbirth, 1, 2) & "/" & mid(dateofbirth, 3, 2) & "/" & mid(dateofbirth, 5, 4)

'Preserved for later use.
'namesData = Split(Replace(strDir, ".xlsx", ""), " ")
'first = namesData(0)
'If UBound(namesData) = 3 Then
'    middlename = namesData(1)
'    last = namesData(2)
'    dateofbirth = namesData(3)
'ElseIf UBound(namesData) = 2 Then
'    last = namesData(1)
'    dateofbirth = namesData(2)
'End If
```

and added

```
reviewNameUserform.middle_Text.Text = middlename
```

Comment: Do `split` by `space` then test first character of each element for number. Use all elements before that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file names have a similar format all the time, you could try using the following code. `filename` can be `John Doe 01011980.xlsx` or `Janey B Deer 02031983.xlsx`.

```
If InStr(filename, ".xlsx") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "missing .xlsx"
ElseIf (Len(filename) - Len(Replace(filename, " ", ""))) < 2 Then
    MsgBox "input format seems weird, not enough spaces"
Else
    filename = Mid(filename, 1, InStr(filename, ".xlsx") - 1)
    dateofbirth  = Mid(filename, InStrRev(filename, " ") + 1)
    filename = Mid(filename, 1, InStrRev(filename, " ") - 1)

    first = Mid(filename, 1, InStr(filename, " ") - 1)
    filename = Mid(filename, InStr(filename, " ") + 1)

    last = Mid(filename, InStrRev(filename, " ") + 1)
    middlename = Trim(Mid(filename, 1, InStr(filename, " ")))
End If
```

The code first removes the .xlsx ending, the takes the birthdate from the end (last space until end), then gets the first name (start until first space), then the family name (last space until end) and whatever is left becomes the middle name.

Comment: An excellent way of formatting the file name down, by continuously rededicating a variable to exclude what's being used. I added `dateofbirth = mid(dateofbirth, 1, 2) & "/" & mid(dateofbirth, 3, 2) & "/" & mid(dateofbirth, 5, 4)` so that it shows up formatted, and this takes the cake. Also allows me to use the middle initial, which I had originally wanted to do but gave up on because of my issues with selecting the right strings out of the file name. No use of arrays too, which I tend to stay away from because they scare me. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

here's a suggestion....

```
Private Sub nextname_Click()

    Dim strDir As String, first As String, last As String, dateofbirth As String, check As String

    strDir = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text
    strDir = Dir
    If strDir = "" Then
        Unload Me
        MsgBox ("I couldn't find any other client files by that name.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    check = Left(strDir, InStr(1, strDir, ".xlsx", vbTextCompare) - 10)

    ''THE SOLUTION IS CONTAINED HEREIN
       check = Trim(check)
       first = Split(check, " ")(LBound(Split(check, " ")))
       last = Split(check, " ")(UBound(Split(check, " ")))

    ''END SOLUTION

    dateofbirth = mid(strDir, Len(strDir) - 12, 2) & "/" & mid(strDir, Len(strDir) - 10, 2) & "/" & mid(strDir, Len(strDir) - 8, 4)

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "C:\filepath\" & strDir

    reviewNameUserform.first_Text.Text = first
    reviewNameUserform.last_Text.Text = last
    reviewNameUserform.dob_Text.Text = dateofbirth
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This does work, and as simple as it is, I think it works less effectively than the other two answers as far as manipulating the data later on (storing in an array, for example) and my own personal understanding of how it works (that's not your fault). The other two answers account for a middle initial too, which I had originally given up on because of my own lack of experience with pulling strings from a file name, but being given the ability to use it was an extra bonus. A good answer though that does solve the problem.

Comment: Happy it helped a bit. I was thinking you did not need the middle initial. and also this code could be limited when the last name contains space like in "EL Paso"...

Answer (score 1):

using the tip from findwindow, you can use the split function.
So, this part of your code:

```
''THE ISSUE IS CONTAINED HEREIN
If InStr(1, check, " * ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    first = Trim(Left(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare) - 2))
    last = Trim(Right(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare) - 2))
Else
    first = Trim(Left(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare)))
    last = Trim(Right(check, Len(check) - InStr(1, check, " ", vbTextCompare)))
End If
''END ISSUE
```

will be modified to:

```
'USING SPLIT
namesData = Split(Replace(strDir,".xlsx","")," ")
first = namesData(0)
If UBound(namesData)=3 Then
    last = namesData(2)
    dateofbirth = namesData(3)
ElseIf UBound(namesData)=2 Then
    last = namesData(1)
    dateofbirth = namesData(2)
End If
```

Comment: this will crash for filenames like 'JohnDoe 01011980.xlsx'. Better use `elseif ubound(namesData) = 2`

Comment: I tested this out and it works just as well as the code I chose to go with. I just don't like arrays that much, but I can see how it would be useful to have a variable that has all the elements in it all the time. I may come back to this later and use this instead of the other because there is less limitation on the array storage than there is using one variable that gets re-purposed. I also added `middlename = namesData(1)` to the `If` statement to pull out the middle initial, which is nice to have.